# XPages way to restore soft deleted document?

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs

Is there a way to restore a deleted document that is located in the trash?  All I know is the @UndeleteDocument formula.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `evaluate` to execute `@UndeleteDocument` on a document from a view of type
*"Shared, contains deleted documents"*

```js
var viewTrash:NotesView = database.getView("trash");
var docToRestore:NotesDocument = viewTrash.getFirstDocument();
var eval = session.evaluate("@UndeleteDocument", docToRestore);
```

This example undeletes the first document from view "trash" which has to be of type "Shared, contains deleted documents".

There is no Java (nor LotusScript) method for undeleting a document. So, evaluate seems to be the appropriate way to handle this.

Comment: Just as an FYI, here is the code I ended up with in a button, that retores all selected docuemnts in the view (using the checkbox in the column):


    var viewcontrol = getComponent("viewPanel1");
    var ids = viewcontrol.getSelectedIds();

    for(i=0;
     i < ids.length; i++){
 var docId=ids[i];
  var doc=database.getDocumentByID(docId); 
 var eval = session.evaluate("@UndeleteDocument", doc);
    }